# R fails to launch Radiant in the Browser

Tags: r, browser, package, rstudio, radiant

I installed Radiant (version 1.4.1) successfully with RStudio (version 1.4.1103) and loaded the package.
But when I try to open Radiant I get the following error:

> radiant:::radiant()
> Starting radiant in the default browser
> Error in system(paste(wmic, "logicaldisk get Caption"), intern = TRUE,  :
> 'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\WMIC.exe logicaldisk get Caption'

I have both Edge and Chrome (Version 115.0.5790.171) browsers.

I couldnt find a similar issue on the Stackoverflow website.
Any idea?